# Ubuntu 13.04 x32 Server CLI - How to Enable - Auto Login via CLI

Tags: auto-login

Ubuntu 13.04 x32 Server Auto Login via CLI

Please advise if there is a native option on Ubuntu 13.04 x32 Server CLI mode (Non GUI)  - Auto Login option

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't (without reprogramming things under the hood in the getty layer or installing X -- the latter of which would remove the CLI-only part of the question).

Unless you are SSHing into the machine from another machine, in which case you can setup SSH keys to log you in automatically that way.